# md-select search filter working based on ng-value but should work on text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-material

I have a md select search filter which have several options.
For Example:
id: 133, label:'Route1'
id: 144, label:'Route2'
id: 155, label:'Route3'
id: 166, label:'Route4'

If i type 1 on the filter, it should show only the first option, but showing all the option because id field has '1' contained in it.

Sample Code:

```
  <md-select id="Route" name="Route" ng-model="filter.RouteIds" multiple data-md-container-class="mdSelect" md-on-close="RouteChange();" ng-required="(sellerFilter && needfilter && '@routeReq' =='required')">
                                                    <md-select-header class="mdSelectHeader">
                                                        <input ng-model="SearchRoute"
                                                               type="search"
                                                               placeholder="@Misc.getResource("APP_CMN_LBL_Search")"
                                                               class="mdSelectSearchBox md-text">
                                                    </md-select-header>
                                                    <md-button style="width: 93%;text-align: left;font-size: 12px;" value="all" ng-click="fnSelectAllRoute()">{{routeToggleText}}</md-button>
                                                    <md-option ng-repeat="route in routes | filter: SearchRoute" value="{{route.value}}" ng-mousemove="fnCheckToggleText(filter.RouteIds.length, routes.length, 'routeToggle');">
                                                        {{route.label}}
                                                    </md-option>
                                                </md-select>
```

Comment: can you include the sample code snippet which you tried?

Comment: Sure. i ll post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify which object property, in this case it is label.

```
filter: { label: SearchRoute}
```

It should be

```
 <md-option ng-repeat="route in routes | filter: { label: SearchRoute}" value="{{route.value}}" ng-mousemove="fnCheckToggleText(filter.RouteIds.length, routes.length, 'routeToggle');">
                                                        {{route.label}}
```

Refer this Sample [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMgQMY)